# Iframe multiple sites from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make something like this:
[image: Example]

I want to be able to dynamically change the iframe based off of the option selected on the dropdown list.

The code I have so far is this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function hidem() {
        document.getElementById('Select').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('test1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('test2').style.display = "none";
        }
    function changeIt(divid) {
        hidem();
        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="Manage" onChange="changeIt(this.value)">
                <option value="Select">Select A Management Window</option>
                <option value="test1">Google</option>
                <option value="test2">Yahoo</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="Select">
                    <h2>Information:</h2>
                    This is a management console
                </div>
                <div id="test1" style="display:none">
                    <h2>Google:</h2>
                    <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div id="test2" style="display:none">
            <h2>Yahoo:</h2>
                    <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </html>
```

but it does not seem to work the way that I have intended. Anyone able to help me out with this?

Thank You,

Dave

Comment: Your HTML is quite messed up. No BODY tag, no FORM tag, no closing TABLE tag. Also you shouldn't be using a table to do HTML layout like this. You should just be using BLOCK level elements such as DIV tags etc.

Comment: How do you want to 'dynamically change the iframe'?

Comment: @EricLeschinski I would like to be able to change the webpage that is loaded based off of the dropdown item.

Comment: jQuery change() event may be simpler to use here: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: You will also have trouble getting pages like Google into your `<iFrame>`, they are setup with a header to prevent being placed inside any framework

Comment: @Dave: Some sites won't allow themselves to be put in any frame inside a page of other site. If that's not what you meant by "not working", what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the huge number of invalid HTML mistakes (which have been highlighted in the comment by @BillyMoat), **I do not believe you will be able to do what you are planning.**

Many large sites (in particular Google) use the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` on their pages.

This means that browser are not allowed to display the page in a frame where the parent is from a different origin (i.e. domain)... this of course depends on the browser understanding this instruction, which most current browsers do.

[Details of the header from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header).

[Here is a blog listing more details about the header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx), including a list of browser which will block the pages being loaded